# Combing ImageViews(vector graphics) and create a custom map using constraint layout , error (broken in different screens)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am  creating a custom map by combining different `ImageViews` (images vector graphics). I used `ConstraintLayout` for this purpose and done in 5.0 inch after changing the screen size 5.5,6,3.7 map broken and ImageViews are arranged in different areas... 
How can I achieve please help me?

ImageViews are vector images

(maybe this is a stupid or silly question please help me, I can't handle this problem, I took more than a week to drow each ImageView in vector.. before downvote please understand my situation :(  )

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kasargod"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.118"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.295"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kasargod" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kannur"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.229"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kannur" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wayand"
            android:layout_width="91dp"
            android:layout_height="108dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.426"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.405"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wayand" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kozhikode"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.355"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.457"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kozhikode" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/malappuram"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.611"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.563"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/malppuram" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/palakd"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.57"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.59"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/palakad" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tcr"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="103dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/malappuram"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.624"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tcr" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ern"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="93dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pathnm"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/kottayam"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.404"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/malappuram"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/palakd"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.495"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ernakulam" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/idukki"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="116dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvm"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pathnm"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/idukki" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kottayam"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ern"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvm"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/idukki"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.060000002"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kottayam" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aalapuzha"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/idukki"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/aalapuzha" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pathnm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="93dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvm"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/kottayam"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/aalapuzha"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/idukki"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pathanamthitta" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/klm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/aalapuzha"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/pathnm"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/aalapuzha"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aalapuzha"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/kollam" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tvm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/aalapuzha"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/klm"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tvm" />




    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Added screenshots below of what i have done

[image]

[image]

5.0,correct map
6.0,arragement borken
3.7,arrangement broken

[image]

Comment: Use single image view and recognize it's parts by multicolor sub images so your main image view does not scattered.

Comment: is there any way combine diffrent imageview  to create a custom map

Comment: no, you need one image view: otherwise you will [almost] never do that the right way...

Comment: mm, is it possible to get clicked area color pixel  ?

Comment: yes it is possible, you need to provide `View.OnTouchListener` to your `ImageView`

Comment: ok  i will check..